# Power series expansion of $z\mapsto \frac{\mathrm e^{z}}{1-tz}$ and $z\mapsto \tan z$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, proof-verification, power-series, taylor-expansion

> 1. Determine the power series expansion and radius of convergence of $z\mapsto \frac{\mathrm e^{z}}{1-tz}$ around $0$ with $t\in\mathbb C$.
> 2. Determine the radius of convergence and the first three non-zero coefficients of the expansion of $\tan z$ around 0.

**Problem 1**

For the first function I used the Cauchy product which yields

$$
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\mathrm e^z}{1-tz}
 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty (tz)^n 
 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^k}{k!}(tz)^{n-k} 
 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{t^{n-k}}{k!}\right) z^n.
\end{align*}
$$

Unfortunately I couldn't simplify this expression anymore - the $\exp$ function is entire but $\frac{1}{1-tz}$ is not for $$z=\frac{1}{t}=\frac{\overline{t}}{t\overline{t}}=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}-\mathrm i\cdot\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$$
with $t=x+\mathrm iy$ for which $\frac{\mathrm e^{z}}{1-tz}$ is not holomorphic. This point is the nearest singularity to the origin and thus the radius of convergence.

**Problem 2**

Since it holds that $$\tan z=\frac{\sin z}{\cos z}$$ the neareast singularity for which $\cos z=0$ is the point $z=\pi/2$. Therefore the expansion around $0$ has this radius of convergence. Furthermore from $\sin z=\cos z\cdot\tan z$ it follows with $\tan$ being odd, that

$$\begin{align*}
 x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}\mp\ldots
 = \left( 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\mp\ldots \right)(ax+bx^3+cx^5+\ldots)
\end{align*}$$

and with comparing coefficients we get $a=1, b=1/3, c=2/15$ with

$$\tan z=z + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{2x^5}{15}+\mathcal{O}(x^7).$$

---

I am still not sure about the radius for problem 1 since I am wondering whether $|tz|<1$ must be true as well. For the second problem I am curious whether a prosaic explanation of "nearest singularity" is sufficient to deduce the maximum radius.

Comment: Both proofs are correct. In particular the arguing with the nearest singularity, whose formalization is a theorem in complex analysis. Note that $|tz|<1$ is immediate from your choice of convergence radius $|1/t|$.